# Can Gibbs free energy determine whether a reaction is endothermic or exothermic?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

In the solution of a problem on thermodynamics, it is mentioned that:

> $\therefore$ Reaction will be endothermic if $\Delta G^{o}>0$

In my knowledge, the Gibbs free energy is usually used for determining the spontaneity of a given reaction. So, this statement is new to me.

Please clarify how we can determine whether a reaction is endothermic or exothermic with Gibbs free energy.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9ZRW.jpg) is the link to the problem for anyone interested.

Comment: This sentence is wrong. A reaction is endothermic if and only if $\Delta H$ is positive. $\Delta G$ has nothing to do here. It can be positive or negative. If $\Delta G$ is positive, the reaction is endoergic !

Comment: @Maurice this is what I was thinking too. I checked the solution only because I got confused between options 1 and 2 (link is in the question).

Comment: @Maurice Can you make it an answer? It sounds trivial, but this is an error that many often confuses.

Comment: It can depend on the previous lines. If they were discussing a reaction that surely increases entropy then the only way for having DelG > 0 is to have an exothermic reaction. As it was a solution it is probably what was meant, and it is correct.

Comment: Just took a look at the link and that is way you should have take it. Whatever they say that is not a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard heat of reaction is related to how $\Delta G^0$ varies with temperature:  $$T^2\frac{d(\Delta G^0/T)}{dT}=-\Delta H^0$$So if $\Delta G^0/T$ is increasing with temperature, the reaction is exothermic and if it is decreasing with temperature, it is endothermic.  And, from this it follows that, if the equilibrium constant is increasing with temperature, the reaction is endothermic and if the equilibrium constant is decreasing with temperature the reaction is exothermic.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is wrong. A reaction is endothermic if and only if $\Delta H$ is positive. $\Delta G$ has nothing to do here. It can be positive or negative. If $\Delta G$ is positive, the reaction is **endoergic**, and not endothermic.